# Pydantic's BaseModel creating attributes as list except in the last one

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I have these classes:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Payment(BaseModel):
    rut: str = None,
    worked_days: int = None,
    base_salary: int = None,
    gratification: int = None,
    liquid_salary: int = None


class RemunerationBook(BaseModel):
    payments: List[Payment] = []
```

After creating an object from RemunerationBook class, then creating the Payment and append it to the list.

```
lre = RemunerationBook()
payment = Payment()
lre.payments.append(payment)
print(lre)
```

I get this when printing:

```
payments=[Payment(rut=(None,), worked_days=(None,), base_salary=(None,), gratification=(None,), liquid_salary=None)]
```

Why every attribute is in a list, except the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
liquid_salary: int = None,
```

because of a point:

`data,` is `tuple` with one element
`data` is a expression (str, int, float,...)

python can not distinguish between `x` and `x` and can not understand if it is tuple or not, so use `comma` if you want `tuple` or if you don't want, remove all `comma`s

one more point:

`()` data is not `list`, but `tuple`... `tuple` has one important difference with `list`: it is immutable like `str`

Comment: "so use colon" no? Use nothing. Remove the commas.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh yes I made a mistake because English is not my first language and distractions, apologies, I meant `comma`

Comment: and I'm not certain that he wants `int` or `tuple`, I try to explain both and leave the choice to him

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad, forgot that commas are not used here. Also, said list because after printing this in a json (via endpoint), I got a list, but I see now that this a tuple internally. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

further to @MoRe answer

```
class Payment(BaseModel):
    rut: str = None,
    worked_days: int = None,
    base_salary: int = None,
    gratification: int = None,
    liquid_salary: int = None
```

changing the last one to

```
class Payment(BaseModel):
    rut: str = None,
    worked_days: int = None,
    base_salary: int = None,
    gratification: int = None,
    liquid_salary: int = None,
```

yields all of them to be `tuples`

you don't need to add different fields with `,` in your models. This will suffice

```
class Payment(BaseModel):
    rut: str = None
    worked_days: int = None
    base_salary: int = None
    gratification: int = None
    liquid_salary: int = None
```

Comment: yup - indeed. fixed.